# Surface Texture object is not getting the frames from a Surface Class

Tags: android, opengl-es, ffmpeg, textures, surface

On the one hand, I have a Surface Class which when instantiated, automatically initialize a new thread and start grabbing frames from a streaming source via native code based on FFMPEG. Here is the main parts of the code for the aforementioned Surface Class:

```
 public class StreamingSurface extends Surface implements Runnable {

    ...

    public StreamingSurface(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        super(surfaceTexture);

        screenWidth  = width;
        screenHeight = height;      
        init();

    }

    public void init() {
        mDrawTop = 0;
        mDrawLeft = 0;
        mVideoCurrentFrame = 0;
        this.setVideoFile();
        this.startPlay();
    }

    public void setVideoFile() {        
        // Initialise FFMPEG
        naInit("");

        // Get stream video res
        int[] res = naGetVideoRes();
        mDisplayWidth = (int)(res[0]);
        mDisplayHeight = (int)(res[1]);

        // Prepare Display
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mDisplayWidth, mDisplayHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        naPrepareDisplay(mBitmap, mDisplayWidth, mDisplayHeight);
    }

    public void startPlay() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            while (2 == mStatus) {
                //pause
                SystemClock.sleep(100);
            }
            mVideoCurrentFrame = naGetVideoFrame();
            if (0 < mVideoCurrentFrame) {
                //success, redraw
                if(isValid()){
                     Canvas canvas = lockCanvas(null);
                     if (null != mBitmap) {
                         canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mDrawLeft, mDrawTop, prFramePaint);
                     }
                     unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            } else {
                //failure, probably end of video, break
                naFinish(mBitmap);
                mStatus = 0;
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

}
```

In my MainActivity class, I instantiated this class in the following way:

```
public void startCamera(int texture)
{
    mSurface = new SurfaceTexture(texture);
    mSurface.setOnFrameAvailableListener(this); 
    Surface surface = new StreamingSurface(mSurface, 640, 360);
    surface.release();        
}
```

I read the following line in the Android developer page, regarding the Surface class constructor:

"Images drawn to the Surface will be made available to the SurfaceTexture, which can attach them to an OpenGL ES texture via updateTexImage()."

That is exactly what I want to do, and I have everything ready for the further renderization. But definitely, with the above code, I never get my frames captured in the surface class transformed to its corresponding SurfaceTexture. I know this because the debugger, for instace, never call the OnFrameAvailableLister method associated with that Surface Texture.

Any ideas? Maybe the fact that I am using a thread to call the drawing functions is messing everything? In such a case, what alternatives I have to grab the frames?

Thanks in advance